# Geometric Intuition of Simplical Sets

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, category-theory, sheaf-theory, simplicial-stuff

In the process of learning about simplical sets, I came across their [geometric realization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set#Geometric_realization), but not quite understanding it, and wondered a few things.

1. What the geometrical realization is, a more intuitive explanation.
2. What a geometrical intuition of a Hausdorff space is.

I understand the basic meaning of simplices and simplical complexes, and in general understand the definition of simplical sets, but don't follow the geometric intuition.

---

Here are my notes if that's helpful. The definition of the geometric realization of a simplical set is:

> There is a functor $|•|: \mathbf{sSet} \to \mathbf{CGHaus}$ called the geometric realization taking a simplicial set $X$ to its corresponding realization in the category of compactly-generated Hausdorff topological spaces.

From my understanding, a Hausdorff space is a space where every point is disconnected from every other point. (I think I pretty much understand functors). So to me this says that it's really not much of a geometric realization, since everything is just an isolated point.

Wondering if one could provide an intuitive understanding of the *geometric realization of a simplical set*.

The reason is, [simplical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set) generalize directed multigraphs, and [abstract simplical complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) generalize [undirected simple graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), so there is a connection of simplical sets to graph theory. If there is a geometric realization of a simplical set, then there is a geometric realization of a directed *multigraph*. This seems like an interesting property, in that you could somehow create a geometric rendering or image of a graph.

From wikipedia:

> A simplicial set $X$ is a collection of sets $X_n, n=0,1,2,...,$ together with certain maps between these sets: the face maps $d_n,i:X_n\to X_{n−1} (n=1,2,3,...\ and\ 0\leq i\leq n)$ and degeneracy maps $s_n,i:X_n\to X_{n+1} (n=0,1,2,...\ and\ 0\leq i\leq n)$.
>
> The elements of $X_n$ are n-simplices of $X$.
>
> Let $Δ$ denote the simplex category. The objects of $Δ$ are nonempty linearly ordered sets of the form
>
> $$[n] = {0, 1, ..., n}$$
>
> with $n \geq 0$.
>
> Simplicial sets are therefore nothing but presheaves on $Δ$.
>
> A presheaf on a category $C$ is a functor $F\colon C^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$
>
> Given a partially ordered set (S,≤), we can define a simplicial set NS, the nerve of S.

Given that a [sheaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)) allows you to attach data to open sets of a topological space, then there is some relation between graphs and data (sheafs) through simplical sets. Combine this with a geometric realization of the simplical set, and it seems you have a geometric representation of the data.

Looking for help on my understanding of the geometric realization of a simplical set, and it's connection to sheafs/data and graph theory. It would be helpful to learn what a picture might look like for an example simplical set / representation.

Comment: Your understanding of Hausdorff spaces is wrong. A Hausdorff space is a space equipped with a topology rich enough to provide, for any two points $x$ and $y$, open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$. This does not mean "everything is just an isolated point". To get an intuitive understanding of the geometric realisation of a simplicial set, it might help to start with the notion of [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex) that gave rise to the much more abstract notion of a simplicial set.

Comment: Most spaces we care about (excluding maybe schemes) are Hausdorff. For example, any manifold is Hausdorff. An isolated point, however, in a space $X$, is a point that is open. Since in a Hausdorff space every point is closed, if every point were isolated then the space would be discrete.